# Let $f,g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, where $g(x)=1-x+x^2$ and $f(x) = ax+b$. If $(g\circ f)(x) = 9x^2-9x+3$, determine $a$, $b$.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I’m struggling with the following problem in my textbook

> Let $f,g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, where $g(x)=1-x+x^2$ and $f(x) = ax+b$. If $(g\circ f)(x) = 9x^2-9x+3$, determine $a$, $b$.

**What I’ve tried:**

So I know $(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$ and if I substitute the functions I get $1-(ax+b)+(ax+b)^2$ and I also know that that equals to $9x^2-9x+3$.

**Now this is where I get stuck**

I’m not sure how to isolate a and b to find there values,I’ve tried rearranging $1-(ax+b)+(ax+b)^2 = 9x^2-9x+3$ into multiple different expressions to get something that I might be able to solve but after a few hours I didn’t get anywhere.

Comment: I like that you’ve thought about this question and provided some evidence that you worked on it, at least a little bit. I’d recommend taking a look at some of the MathJax tutorials on this site so your posts are more readable (it isn’t too hard, but it might feel clunky at first; the payoff is that your posts will be more likely to receive positive attention). +$1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace $x$ with $0$ then $1-(a \cdot 0+b)+(a \cdot 0+b)^2=9(0)^2-9(0)+3$

Upon simplifying both sides you get $1-b+b^2=3 $ Solve for b

Find $a$ in a similar way with using the $b$ you found. Choose a different $x$ though.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Expand $(ax+b)^2 - (ax+b) + 1$ and then match the coefficients according to $x^2$ and $x$ with the function $9x^2 - 9x + 3$.